# How to remove spaces in only the top row in excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel

I want to clean up some data that's having trouble importing into Arc.  I want to know a way to clear spaces in only the top row in excel.  Sometimes there is one hidden before or after the row name and it causes Arc to import them incorrectly.  It will return an invalid SQL statement when it tries to draw in Arc.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Comment: If you are dealing with a lot of messy data have you seen what was called Google refine? Have a look [here](http://openrefine.org/).

Comment: Save as CSV, then nothing is hidden and all formulas are calculated, edit in notepad (or your choice of text editor) which will do find & replace but it's just as easy to do the top line manually. After you're done import to personal geodatabase or file geodatabase format, Excel can have hiccups in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Replace** function detailed in [this guide](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/649-excel-remove-spaces.html):

> Remove all spaces with the Replace function
>
> Sometimes, we want to remove all spaces between character and numbers
>   in a range, we can use Replace function to solve it.
>
> 1. Highlight the range that you want to remove all spaces.
> 2. Click Home > Find & Select > Replace…, the Find and Replace dialog box will pop out.
> 3. In the Find what box, press the space bar once, don’t input anything in the Replace with box, then click Replace All. There will
>      be a prompt message telling you how many spaces have been removed. See
>      screenshot:

[image]